# prototype - remove class, to elements selected by ClassName

Tags: javascript, prototype, classname

### http://jsfiddle.net/9UQwM/1/

the script removes class from the elements in an alternating pattern,

most importantly why?

and what can be done to fix the problem?

```
Object.prototype.removeClass = function (class_name) {
    if (this.length) {
        for (i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
            this[i].classList.remove(class_name);
        }
    }
}
document.getElementsByClassName("test").removeClass("test");
```

Comment: that fails on all levels

Comment: Excuse me: Don't put this on `Object.prototype`. Use `NodeList.prototype`. Adding it to `Object.prototype` adds this method to all objects. You don't want it on all objects, and putting it on all objects can really be hostile to other code.

Comment: what shall i do when i want to apply it to `document.getElementById("test")`, NodeList won't work :/ ?? helpp

Comment: Add it also to `HTMLElement.prototype` for that case. Of course, you won't need a `for` loop for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because when you delete, the next index moves down one. Loop in the opposite direction.

```
for (var i = this.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) { ... }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9UQwM/2/

Using a while loop might bring more into it

```
Object.prototype.removeClass = function(class_name) {
    if (this.length) {
        while(this.length>0) {
            console.log(this.length);
            this[0].classList.remove(class_name);
        }
    }
}
document.getElementsByClassName("test").removeClass("test");
```

The output would be 7,6,5,4,3,2,1

http://jsfiddle.net/9UQwM/4/

So `this` is updated when you remove the class

Comment: i see, didn't know the changing of the index of the elements was that quick

Answer (score 1):

I found another workaround than was described by [@epascarello](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14409442/1249581). Making the pure JS array out of `this` does the job well:

```
var that = Array.prototype.slice.call(this);
for (var i = 0; i < that.length; i++) {
    that[i].classList.remove(class_name);
}
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/9UQwM/3/

Comment: very nice, wouldn't @epascarello method be marginally better performace-wise

Comment: @YusafKhaliq To answer this question I need to know why the index moves to the next element on class removal. At the moment I have no idea why it happens.

Comment: I don't know why but i understand why and i don't know about performance, i'm just assuming because while epascarello's answer only has a loop yours contains the array.slice method and a loop

Comment: @YusafKhaliq I have the same perceptions, however it might happen that array slice takes not so much time.

Comment: @YusafKhaliq You're welcome :) BTW, [Nathan](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14409380/prototype-remove-class-to-elements-selected-by-classname/14409505#comment20052372_14409380) raised a very good idea to replace `Object` to `NodeList`. That really makes sense.

Comment: but what about when i want to apply it to `document.getElementById("test")`

Comment: Actually, believe it or not, but my perception is that espascarello's may be slower in some browsers. Accessing `length` on a NodeList can be rather slow because the length can change through lots of different operations (as you saw when you tried the original loop from your question). Accessing `length` on a sliced array, however, is *very* fast, and the browser has a lot easier time optimizing an array than a `NodeList`. The slice method itself is very fast.

Comment: Do not assume, run a test on jsperf. ;)