# For loop only iterates once when trying to remove classes from elements

Tags: javascript, dom, for-loop

In Javascript I have a function that should find the elements on the page that have the "connected" class, and when a button is clicked the classes for these elements are cleared. I have written this code:

```
var prev_connected = document.getElementsByClassName("connected");
if (prev_connected.length > 0) {
    for (var j = 0; j < prev_connected.length; j++) {
        prev_connected[j].removeAttribute("class");
    }
}
```

However, it only ever deletes the class attribute of the first "connected" element on the page. When I have two "connected" elements, I have confirmed that the "prev_connected" array does hold 2 values, but for some reason the for loop never reaches the 2nd one. Is there something I'm doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The result of `getElementsByClassName` is live, meaning that as you remove the class attribute it will also remove that element from the result. Using `querySelectorAll` is more widely supported and returns a static NodeList.

Also, you can more easily iterate the list using a for...in loop.

**I would not recommend making an extra copy of the live list just to make it static**, you should use a method that returns a static NodeList instead.

```js
var prev_connected = document.querySelectorAll(".connected");
document.getElementById('demo').onclick = function() {
    for(var i in Object.keys(prev_connected)) { 
        prev_connected[i].removeAttribute("class");
    }
}
```

```css
.connected {
  background: rgb(150,200,250);
}
```

```html
<div class="connected">Hello</div>
<div class="connected">Hello</div>
<div class="connected">Hello</div>
<div class="connected">Hello</div>
<div class="connected">Hello</div>
<button id="demo">Remove the classes!</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is due to `prev_connected` being a live nodelist. When you update the element with that class it removes it from the nodelist which means the length of the nodelist reduces by one which means `j` is trying to find element 2 in an nodelist of length 1 which is why it doesn't work after the first iteration.

You can see this happening in the console in [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fz08w8np/6/).

One way you can fix this is by converting the nodelist to an array:

```
var prev_connected = [].slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName("connected"));
```

Comment: This fixed my problem, as did setting j to prev_connected.length-1 and then decrementing down. Yeah it must be because of it being a live nodelist.

Answer (score 0):

You should iterate in the opposite direction and use `elem[i].classList.remove('name')` for removing class name from each element [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sherali/ay8bbd9q/)

```
document.getElementById("button").onclick = function () {
    var prev_connected = document.getElementsByClassName("connected");
    console.log(prev_connected);
    for (var i = prev_connected.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        prev_connected[i].classList.remove("connected");
        console.log(i, prev_connected[i - 1]);
    }
}
```

There are another answers: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14409442/4365315